# Post-fetch sorting / Workaround for NSSortDescriptor + NSFetchRequest / Sorting a tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

My quest to collect the scattered, magical pieces of code needed to create an animated and dynamically updating UITableView - artifacts hidden in the dark and ghastly depths of Apple Inc's feared dungeon, The Documentation - has with the help of the ever-friendly townsfolk and everyday heroes of Stack Overflow finally been completed.

But worry not, the end of this quest is but the beginning of a new one.

---

I have one UITableView. That tableView is hooked up to a NSFetchedResultsController. The FRC delegate methods are all up and running as pr. Apple's example code.

I have two NSManagedObjectContexts:

1. The Truth. This MOC is only inserted to / deleted from when the user adds or deletes an object.
2. The scratch pad. This is the MOC that the tableView's FRC is hooked up to. Any change here is reflected in the tableView with nice animations.

The scratch pad is seeded with objects from The Truth, but it is never saved. This means that I can insert and delete (show and hide) objects here to my heart's content, all while the tableView politely updates.

(To anyone reading this in an attempt to implement something like this I would say: get acquainted with [managedObjectContext objectWithID:id])

---

My question comes from the need to sort the tableView. As made clear to me by reading about NSSortDescriptor in conjunction with NSFetchRequest, using a sortDescriptor simply won't fly when one's using a SQLite store. The Docs say, "instead you should sort the returned array in memory". All-right then! But how do I go about doing that?

Where, in my logic as described above, do I inject this sorted array? Wherever I turn, there seems to be problems.

Comment: Can you not use a property on your entity for sorting, or are you trying to do a more complex sort? (With Maths and what not)

Comment: Here's a link explaining what I want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271008/nssortdescriptor-with-arbitrary-sorting. FRC+CoreData+SQLite does not support NSSortDescriptor blocks :( In addition this is also happening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212042/sorting-an-inserted-object-in-a-nsfetchedresultscontroller.

Comment: Here's info on why NSSortDescriptor blocks doesn't work in this configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106184/custom-sorting-with-nsfetchedresultcontroller-subclassing-nssortdescriptor. Official documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html (under Problems with Fetching).

Comment: Yeah, the limitation with filtering/sorting in NSFRC backed by SQLite3 was the motivation behind BSFRC. Unfortunately, I just don't have the time to develop it anymore, and I no longer need its functionality. You're welcome to fork it - https://github.com/blindingskies/BSFetchedResultsController. Also, just think carefully about your data model, you can do simply sorting on properties in the model, so if you to sort on a calculated value, add it as a property, and literally calculate it and set it. You can seed a MOC with objects, calculate the values, and have a NSFRC watch that.