# UISearchDisplayController/NSFetchedResultsController with custom sort order

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller, nssortdescriptor

I'm implementing a search feature in my app. I would like the user to look up a word simultaneously in multiple attributes of a given Entity.

Here is an example for an Entity with 3 String attributes: **Person**
(firstName, lastName, notes)

Let's use a mock dataset with 3 people:

- "Emily", "Bridges", "She will be in town real soon."
- "Johnny", "Williams", "This dude is really cool."
- "Will", "Smith", "He does not remember anything for some reason."

Now, let's assume the user is looking up the occurence **"will"** and that we run a case insensitive search. All three previously described people will match the word "will" thanks to the use of an **orPredicateWithSubpredicates**

Ideally I would like the results to be displayed in this order for relevancy purposes:

- "Will", "Smith", "He does not remember anything for some reason."
- "Johnny", "Williams", "This dude is really cool."
- "Emily", "Bridges", "She will be in town real soon."

For this search feature "firstName" is more relevant than "lastName" which are both more relevant than the "notes" attribute.

Since I'm using a UISearchDisplayController, I also use an **NSFetchedResultsController** which requires an **NSSortDescriptor**. The problem for me now is what attribute/key I am going to use to init the NSSortDescriptor?

I've been through many posts already and thought a transient property could help me with this issue, but I can't figure out how/when to set up this transient property which could be named something like "sortKey" and be set to these values:

- 1: For a match on "firstName"
- 2: For a match on "lastName"
- 3: For a match on "notes"

Eventually I guess I could try to run three different requests but then I'd have to give up using NSFetchedResultsController and all its magic...

I don't know whether I'm hitting the limits of NSFetchedResultsController or something but any pointer would be great, thanks!

Joss.

Comment: I'd consider subclassing NSSortDescriptor instead. A transient property would be good if you only needed data from a single object but you need to compare multiple fields from multiple objects to determine your desired sort order.

Comment: Thanks @Wain for your suggestion. Sounds like a neat idea. I've just tried this out but can't figure out how to "force" the call to compareObject:toObject: message. There is an interesting post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106184/custom-sorting-with-nsfetchedresultcontroller-subclassing-nssortdescriptor). Seems like I'm gonna have to give up on using NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: Interesting post. And as it says you could use the FRC to monitor for changes and trigger your custom sort processing...