# NSFetchedResultsController: keep sort order same as IN predicate

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have a list of uids, and I need to get Core Data objects with those uids:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid IN %@", uids];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Now, I want to keep the objects in the same order as the listed uids. So if the array is [3, 1, 2], then I want the returned objects to be in that order as well.

Not setting an sort descriptor isn't an option with `NSFetchedResultsController`, so what should I set the sort descriptor to?

Comment: In the end I'm using an intermediary method that sorts my results, instead of directly using the fetched results controller.

Answer (score 0):

The sort descriptor can be set on a `NSFetchRequest` instance.

```
[request setSortDescriptors:descriptors];
```

where `descriptors` is an array of [`NSSortDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instances.

A `NSSortDescriptor` can be created as follows:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorForKey = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"someKey" ascending:YES]; // YES or NO based on your needs
```

About your question, what is the order of `uids`? Based on my experience (I haven't think on this until now) you cannot do what you are trying to achieve. Anyway, you could just replicate the descriptor for your `uids` in the `NSFetchRequest`.

Maybe someone could have some other ideas.

Comment: Basically what I have a sorted array of id's (4,2,3,1) and the NSFetchedResultsController needs to return those 4 objects in that order. I'm afraid this is impossible as well.

Comment: @mixedCase Did you apply a sort descriptor to `uids` array? If you apply the same descriptor you use for `uids` to your `request`, you will have same results.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If I create a NSSortDescriptor with key uid, then the objects will be sorted on uid (either ascending or descending). I want to keep them in the order I used them in the IN predicate.

Comment: @mixedCase I mean that if you apply a sort descriptor to `uids`, you can use the same sort descriptor in the `request`. Is it ok?

Comment: Ah no, the array is remotely downloaded and sorted on the server. It's just an array with some integers.

Comment: @mixedCase so you could just create your custom descriptor replicating the logic you used in the server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168141/core-data-table-view-section-sort-by-weekdays-using-nssortdescriptor

Answer (score 0):

Objects in a persistent store are unordered. Typically you should impose order at the controller or view layer, based on an attribute such as creation date. If there is order inherent in your data, you need to explicitly model that.(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdFAQ.html)